# angularjs 2 select box loaded data but select box is not visible on browser

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box which is populating from database. In the browser, I can see the select box template with all data from DB but not able to see the select box in the UI in a table.

**`Controller.js`**:

```
$scope.GetCvSRCDetails = function() {
    $scope.loader.loading = true;
    crudFactory.getDataList("getcvsrcadetailalerts", "null")
    .success(function (rcdata) {
        $scope.cvsRCDetails = rcdata;
    });
};
$scope.GetCvSRCDetails();
```

**`crudfactory.js`**

```
getDataList: function (ctrName, objId) {
    url = serviceBase + "api/" + ctrName + "/" + objId;
    return $http.get(url);//, authService.setHeader($http));
},
```

**`HTML`**

```
<td>
    <select data-ng-options="rc.RCL1 for rc in cvsRCDetails"
            data-ng-model="col">
    </select> 
</td>
```

On the basis of this, I need to populate another select box, but first I am not able to see the first Select box.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked whether cvsRCDetails contains any elements? And does these elements have property ´RCL1´? Also, probably I'm wrong, but I do not remember any angularjs version contains "data-" prefix

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue with using below code.

```
<select ng-model="col" material-select>
                                <option ng-repeat="rc in cvsRCDetails">{{rc.RCL1}}</option>
                            </select>
```

I just added material-select in select tag.

Thanks,
Bharat